# crossrider: store snapshot of bookmarks in local database and compare to current bookmarks list

Tags: javascript, jquery, local, crossrider

How do I store a snapshot of the bookmarks list and then compare that to the current bookmars list every n amount of time with a conditional statement that outputs any bookmarks that have been added? I have been trying to do this to no avail.

It would be great if you could provide a code example but if you just want to explain it conceptually it would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, you can achieve your goal by storing the previous bookmarks list in the extension's local database using [appAPI.db.async](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db.async), comparing it to the current bookmark list obtained using [appAPI.bookmarks.getTree](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.bookmarks-method-getTree), and sending it to your API server using [appAPI.request.post](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.request-method-post).

You can use the following code in your *background.js* file as your starting point for handling the bookmarks lists and write your own comparison function (getChanges) as you require:

```
appAPI.ready(function() {
  // Poll every 30 seconds
  setInterval(function() {
    appAPI.db.async.get('prevBookmarks', function(value) {
      // Load or initialize previous bookmarks list
      var prevBookmarks = (value) ? value : {};

      // Get current bookmarks
      appAPI.bookmarks.getTree(function(nodes) {
        // Save bookmark list for next comparison
        appAPI.db.async.set('prevBookmarks', nodes);

        // In your getChanges functions, traverse the bookmark trees collating
        // changes and then post then to your API server using appAPI.request
        var changes = getChanges(prevBookmarks, nodes);
        appAPI.request.post({
          url: http://yourAPIserver.com,
          postData: changes,
          contentType: 'application/json'
        });
      });
    });
  }, 30 * 1000);
});
```

Comment: Doesnt this just replace prevBookmarks with an updated prevBookmarks and then compare it to current bookmarks?